# .NET Assembly References Overview

Tags: .net

Does anybody know of a good tool or piece of code that will allow me to produce an overview of the assembly references a project is using?

I'd like to see the Assembly Name, version, path, etc of all the assemblies in a spreadsheet format.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe not exactly what you're looking for, but see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/456780/software-visualization-for-c

Answer (score 2):

You can always use http://dependencyvisualizer.codeplex.com/. You can also set different output formats (i.e. spreadsheet).

Answer (score 1):

`Reflector for .NET` will show you the references an assembly has (as with `ildasm`), but the .NET `Assembly` type also has this information.

So probably easiest to create your own tool that uses `Assembly.Load` to get the `Assembly` instance and call its [`GetReferencedAssemblies`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getreferencedassemblies.aspx) method. You can then save the data in whatever format you like (possibly including automating Excel).